# How to find out whether an NSWindow is active

Tags: cocoa, macos

How can I find out if an `NSWindow` is active? i.e. if I have some windows on the desktop then only one is active and has colored window buttons and receives keyboard and mouse events. How can I find out if my window is the active one? To find out if the window is miniaturized there is the `isMiniaturized` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for `NSWindow`'s [`-isKeyWindow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/isKeyWindow) method.  "is key" means that it receives keyboard events.

Comment: OP should also look at `-isMainWindow` and understand the distinction between key and main windows.

Comment: Link explaining @KenThomases' point: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html